# Using Flow Player with ASP.NET MVC 4, "html5: Video file not found"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, path, flowplayer

Here is some code from the view:

```
<div class="flowplayer">
   <video>
      <source type="video/mp4" src="~/Content/Videos/HowItWorksRegistration1.mp4">
   </video>
</div>
```

I get the error: "html5: Video file not found"

But if I link to a web url for a random .mp4 video, it works. Also, earlier in the view, I have images with the same relative path and that works. I've double checked the path and even tried to put the video in the same directory (with updated path), and that did not work.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try `<source type="video/mp4" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Videos/HowItWorksRegistration1.mp4")">`

Comment: @RowanFreeman in MVC4 `@url.Content` & `@Href` are not required.  Just `~/..` is needed and Razor will convert it.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check is can you browse to the video url and play it in the browser.

- If you get a 404 it's because the path is wrong.
- If it does not play it is because the browser does not support that video.

[HTML5 wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video) shows what video formats what browsers support.

Answer (score 0):

Some Chrome versions have issues with playing MP4 content. Workaround: List a WEBM before the MP4 source and/or set preload="none" as video tag attribute.

Answer (score 0):

you should add :

```
<link href="~/Scripts/Video2/flowplayer-5.4.6/skin/minimalist.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Scripts/Video2/x/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Scripts/Video2/x/pygments.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Scripts/Video2/x/playlist.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Video/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Video2/flowplayer-5.4.6/flowplayer.min.js"></script>
```

Then you should use this :

```
<div class="flowplayer" style="width: 450px; height: 260px" data-ratio="0.416" data-swf="//releases.flowplayer.org/5.4.6/flowplayer.swf">
        <video style="width: 450px; height: 260px" src="~/Content/Videos/HowItWorksRegistration1.mp4"></video>
    </div>
```

Comment: http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-use-flowplayer-as-your-web-video-player-beginners-guide/